# Show that $\mathbb{A}^n$ on the Zariski Topology is not Hausdorff, but it is $T_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

There was an exercise I could not do. So the property is $T_1$ if for every pair of distinct points, $P, Q \in X$, there is an open subset $U$ containing $P$ but not $Q$ and another open subset $V$ containing $Q$ but not $P$.

So I was asked to show if the base field is infinite, then $\mathbb{A}^n$ is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.

I can show that it's not Hausdorff (I believe this is right). So let $k$ be an infinite field, then we have $U$ and $V$ which are two nonempty subsets which are open, thus $U^c$ and $V^c$ finite so by Demorgan's law we have $(U \cap V)^c =U^c \cup V^c$ which is also finite, so this implies that $U\cap V$ is non-empty so it can't be Hausdorff.

But I can't seem to really show that it's $T_1$

Any ideas how to approach this?

Thank you.

Comment: Let $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{A}^n$.  Consider the polynomials $x_i-a_i$.

Comment: This means that you should find a polynomial vanishing at P and not at Q and another polynomial vanishing at Q and not at P.

Answer (score 7):

Since Seth has proved that $\mathbb A^n$ is $T_1$, I'll prove that $\mathbb A^n$ is not Hausdorff [Seth correctly pointed out that Jen's proof is incorrect for $n\gt1$] .

By considering complements of open subsets Hausdorffness amounts to proving that the union of two closed **strict** subsets $X_1\subsetneq \mathbb A^n, X_2\subsetneq \mathbb A^n$ is not the whole affine space: $X_1 \cup X_2\subsetneq \mathbb A^n$.
Now, writing $X_i=V(I_i)$, the inequality $X_i \neq \mathbb A^n$ is equivalent to $f_i\in I_i$ for some **non zero** $f_i\in k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$.
We have $X_1\cup X_2=V(I_1\cdot I_2)\subset V(f_1\cdot f_2)$, so that it is enough to prove $V(f_1\cdot f_2)\neq \mathbb A^n$  to obtain the desired conclusion $X_1 \cup X_2\neq \mathbb A^n$.
But $V(f_1\cdot f_2)\neq \mathbb A^n$ is clear: it results from the well-known fact that if $k$ is an infinite field a **non-zero**  polynomial     $g(T_1,\dots,T_n)\in k[T_1,\dots,T_n] $ (here $g=f_1\cdot f_2$) cannot vanish on all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n$ .

Comment: Assuming (for the sake of the discussion) that the OP knew about irreducibility, can't your proof be shortened by noticing that $\Bbb A ^n$ is irreducible (because $k[T_1, \dots, T_n]$ does not contain divisors of $0$)?

Comment: @Alex M. No, absence of divisors of zero does not suffice:  $\mathbb F_2[T_1,...,T_n]$ does not contain divisors of zero and yet  $\mathbb A^n(\mathbb F_2)$ is not irreducible (it is discrete).

Comment: Hmm... now I'm lost. Let me quote straight from Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry": *"Therefore, a closed set $X$ is irreducible if and only if its coordinate ring $k[X]$ has no zerodivisors."*. Since $k[\Bbb A^n] = k[T_1, \dots, T_n]$, wouldn't it follow that $\Bbb A^n$ is irreducible? Or maybe this is true only for infinite fields (such as the algebraically closed ones)?

Comment: @Alex M. Yes, Shafarvich works over algebraically closed fields : cf. page 22, first line of section 2.

Answer (score 5):

$T_1$ is equivalent to single point sets being closed.

Let $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{A}^n$.  Consider the zero locus of the polynomials $x_i-a_i$ where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.

For your proof of non-Hausdorffness it looks like you are assuming that $\mathbb{A}^n$ has the cofinite topology, which is not true in general.  $\mathbb{A}^1$ does have the cofinite topology, but $\mathbb{A}^2$ does not, since for example, the polynomial $x\in\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ has infinitely many zeros.

Comment: Okay, so let's say $a = (a_1, ... , a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, \dots , b_n)$. So if we consider the zero locus of the polynomials of $x_i - a_i$, this means that $a$ satisfies this polynomial but $b$ doesn't. Similarly for $x_i - b_i$, so this means it has to be $T_1$.

Comment: Not quite.  What I meant is that the common zeros of the collection $x_i-a_i$ where $i$ varies from $1$ to $n$ is exactly the point $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.  But if you want to follow Robert Green's suggestion then let $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\neq(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.  Then there is $i$ such that $a_i\neq b_i$.  Now with this $i$ fixed, consider the polynomials $x_i-a_i$ and $x_i-b_i$.